What does the "pick up" label mean in the Jubeat 2008 arcade game?
In the 2008 arcade version of Jubeat, when selecting a song to play, some song icons have a "Pick up" label in the top right corner. What does the "Pick up" label mean?



"pick up" label means that those songs are new songs in the current version.
This was introduced in jubeat festo (2018) when the game introduced the concept of "jubility", a player level skill where it counts top 30 played songs each from "common" (songs from previous versions) and "pick up" (new songs from current version).
Reference: jubeat official X (Twitter) account

【最後にも確認できます！】jubilityは「common」と「pick up」の上位30曲ずつの総合jubility値によって構成されてます。「common」対象曲はfesto以前の楽曲となっており、「pick up」対象曲はfestoから登場した新曲になります！ #jubeat #jubeat10周年 #festo情報

For this case, the shown "pick up" songs are おにけもだんす, Gray Heaven, and エジソン from jubeat Ave (2022).
